# AngularJS: Binding a corresponding name to a path

Tags: angularjs

I'm pretty new to AngularJS and some things are not that clear to me how it would be done using this library.

I'm creating a multi-language website and I was wondering how something like this would normally been done:

```
<a ng-href='#!/{{ path }}'>{{ nameOfpath }}</a>
```

Where `nameOfpath` is not defined.

I ended up using a service for mapping all corresponding names to the path and using a filter to get the path name. So I could write it like this:

```
<a ng-href='#!/{{ path }}'>{{ path | linkname }}</a>
```

Simplified code I used looks like this:

```
module.factory('linkService', [function () {
    return function () {
        return {
            'nl': {
                name: 'nl'
            },

            'nl/home': {
                name: 'Home'
            },

            'nl/shop': {
                name: 'Assortiment'
            }
        };
    };
}]).filter('linkName', ['linkService', function (linkService) {
    var links = linkService();
    return function (path) {
        return links[path] ? links[path] : '...';
    }
}]);
```

I figured this wouldn't be the correct way to go.

**Question:** How would you guys do this?

Comment: I answered based on your service, If you provide more information maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Alright. The example above is the basic idea of hardcoding the names. Preferably I would like to be able to generate names from within a function. So I could use that function for path parameters (e.g. `shop/brand/:brandName`.It doesn't have to work with a service. How would you do this?

Comment: You have to put more information of how your routes are formed and how you generate the names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You can create a directive:

```
app.directive('myHref', function(linkService){
  var links = linkService();
  return {
    link: function(scope,elm,attrs){

      attrs.$observe('myHref', function(path){            
        attrs.$set('href', path);
        elm.text(links[path] || '...' );    
      })

    }
  }
})
```

#### And use it like so:

```
<a my-href='#!/{{ path }}'></a>
```